# JMeter HTTP Sampler - Request GET only successful on homepage, any other page returns 404

Tags: http, get, jmeter, http-status-code-404

### Description

When using the HTTP request sampler in JMeter for a specific website I can't seem to fetch any page other than the home page, `http://<website>.com/`. If I try to access some other page, say, `http://<website>.com/about-us` I get a `404` response.

In the request sampler there are two fields `Server Name or IP` and `Path`, and I know it's a common error to fill these out incorrectly. I've tried multiple different ways to enter these correctly. IP with and without the `about-us` part, with and without `/` etc.

I've tried this with other websites and have seen no problems, so my assumption is that there is something specific to the website I'm testing.

Here is where I get confused about it. When you look in the `View Result Tree` you see under `Request > Request Body` a correctly entered get request. If I enter this into my browser, or do a manual get request on this url on https://reqbin.com/ it fetches the website just fine.

The only discrepancy I see between this website and other websites that I don't have this problem with is that the website's about page etc., don't end with a `/`. If you add the backslash at the end of the URL you can't access the website.

### Steps to reproduce

- Add HTTP sampler in JMeter
- enter server name under `Server Name or IP`, i.e. `www.<website>.com`
- enter path to `Path`, i.e. `/about-us`
- run test and watch result in `View Result Tree`

### Expected Result

HTTP Response 200

### Actual Result

HTTP Response 404

#### Response Body

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /about-us</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Response Headers

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 147
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 28 Jan 2020 17:11:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

### Key notes

- The request body `GET http://<website>.com/about-us` is a valid link if posted in a browser or if used with https://reqbin.com/
- the about page doesn't end with a `/`, I don't know if this is relevant

Answer (score 0):

If you don't share the site hostname with us we cannot help, so far I can only suggest:

1. Consider building your test plan using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), both approaches should create the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler(s) as building test plan manually opens doors to mistakes (i.e. your configuration can contain non-printable characters like space or line breaks)
2. Increasing [logs verbosity for HTTP protocol components](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http" level="debug" />
   ```

   and if necessary

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
   ```

   this way you will see for sure what request(s) JMeter is sending